# Jenkins performance plugin for JMeter shows Trend Charts and Trend Report only for few minutes after last successful build

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

I am facing this peculiar issue with Jenkins Performance Plugin for JMeter runs where after a successful build graphs on job page and trend reports as shown in below images are visible only for few minutes and after some time they are no longer available. Only Last report shows link works but trend report and other charts disappear.

### These pictures are just after a successful build

[image]

[image]

[image]

### And following are the pictures after few minutes if I refresh the page or revisit the page:

[image]
[image]

If I access the trend report URL directly then I am able to access the Trend Report, but as you can see there is no link available on performance trend page for this job.

Answer (score 1):

Its a problem when using on demand minions. We had the exact same issue where results disappeared but if you saved the URL they still worked. It seems the results go away when the Jenkins job's minion would timeout (terminate). I changed that trigger job (where I have configured the performance plugin) to run on "master". Now the problem is fixed. No harm letting my trigger run on master since it doesn't really put much load on jenkins, its just waiting for the multi-branch pipeline job to finish and then collects the results and publishes the performance report.

Comment: Hello @Mike, Thanks a lot for replying. If I understand correctly, by on demand minions you mean on demand agents? We are in-fact running our perf tests on azure jenkin agents that spin up with each job that is run.

I have individual jenkins job that runs on agent for each service to performance test it with few jmeter parameters like users, ramp up time etc.. here how can I run it on master as master node doesn't have jmeter installed? Any suggestion in this regards would be highly appreciable. Also kindly consider answering in easy to understand terms as I am new to Jenkins.. Thanks again

Comment: right the azure jenkins agents are the same. So we have a parent jenkins job we call a "trigger" that tells our jmeter job to run but explicitly supplies the parameters unique to that trigger name (environment, url, thread count, duration, etc). The triggers use the build step "Trigger/call builds on other projects" and supply the parameters. So they wait for the jmeter test to finish, copy the artifacts, and publish the performance report. I now make sure my trigger runs on master and it fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using [Jenkins LTS 2.346.2](https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.346.2/)

If you do believe it's a plugin issue and not your Jenkins (check [Jenkins logs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/)) /browser (try opening an [incognito window](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history) and if this doesn't help check if you can see anything suspicious in [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)) one you can [raise a ticket](https://www.jenkins.io/participate/report-issue/redirect/#15803) for this.

If you're a BlazeMeter customer you can try requesting the fix as a priority by opening a [BlazeMeter Support Ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)

Comment: Thanks for replying @dmitri-t, I tried opening in incognito window and even tried dev tools to see if there are any errors while page is loaded but couldn't find any specific issue. We use jenkins 2.204.2
Could you please suggest any more debugging steps that I can use to fix this issue?